# Getting the initial path of msoFileDialogFolderPicker

Tags: vba, excel

The application I am working on requires the users to select a folder using msoFileDialogFolderPicker, and it rather usefully opens the folder picker in the last location. However, our users occasionally change a folder name in the path. This causes a windows 'location unavailable' dialog box. This scares our users as they don't know what's happening.

My question is, how do I find out what the initial folder location is going to be? I can then trap for it just set it to a default location instead.

My code very simply is

```
GetFolder As String
Set folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With folder
    .Title = "Please Select a Folder"
    .InitialFileName = "C:\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .Show <> -1  Then Goto EndSub
    GetFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    MsgBox fldr.InitialFileName
End Sub
```

Comment: That's it thanks! I also had to take out `.InitialFileName = "C:\"`. It was still defaulting to the last folder, but that variable still read C:\. Bizarre, but fixed

Comment: @Smittey  What is interesting to me is that the *Object* has default properties.

Comment: I thought this was correct, but I'm mistaken. This does not produce the path of the FolderPicker on `.show`. It might be unique to me, but it displays the path of one level lower.

Comment: In some environments you will get a different value before and after the **.Show**

Comment: That's annoying. I may end up having to save the path of the folder in a hidden sheet or something, and use that for reference on a `If Dir(,)` then. Doesn't seem too elegant. But oh well

Answer (score 2):

Would rather comment to respond to a comment in the previous answer, but I don't have the "reputation" to do that, so forgive me for using one answer to respond to another.

I discovered a subtlety in .InitialFileName.  When I use this snippet,

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop"
    If .Show = -1 Then
        Get_Folder = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Get_Folder = ""
    End If
End With
```

VBA puts "Desktop" in the "Folder name:" box at the bottom of the dialog window, and simply defaults to the previous folder used in Windows.  But when I put a backslash at the end of the path, as I do here,

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop\"
    If .Show = -1 Then
        Get_Folder = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Get_Folder = ""
    End If
End With
```

the Folder Dialog does not use the last used folder, it actually selects the folder "C:\Users<Username>\Desktop".  Having so much depend on a simple backslash is not the best design, but I doubt Microsoft will change that.